# Recursive division using only subtraction and addition

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a function that returns the quotient and remainder of a division after taking two arguments, the first a dividend, the second a divisor by recursively subtracting the divisor from the dividend.

```
def recursive_division (a, b, c = 0):
    if b == 0: 
        return ("(Cannot divide by zero)","(Cannot divide by zero)")
    elif a < b:
        return (c,a)
    else:
        return recursive_division (a - b, b, 1 + c)
```

Is there any way to find the quotient without having the default variable c defined as zero in the function... With the function only having two arguments when defined and only returning something based on a or b? (example below)

```
def recursive division (a, b)
    ...
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: Yes, you can avoid the `c` by increasing the divisor when returning from the recursive_division call.

Comment: @Lucero can you show me what you mean

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ what do you want me to change?

Comment: @ZacTaylor: your question was being reopened by the community after you added an actual question to the post. I just cast the final vote.

Comment: @Lucero: It has been re-opened, so you can post your answer.

Comment: @Lucero Thanks it works perfectly but can you explain how?

Comment: @ZacTaylor I'm not sure how I can explain better than the code explains itself, but here I go. When the recursion method is called, it is called with the first parameter being a-b, which means that the result returned will have a quotient which is 1 less. This 1 is then added to the quotient part of the result received from the recursion call before being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid using `c` by increasing the divisor returned by the `recursive_division` recursion.

Something like that (not tested):

```
def recursive_division (a, b):
    if b == 0: 
        return ("(Cannot divide by zero)","(Cannot divide by zero)")
    elif a < b:
        return (0, a)
    else:
        (x, y) = recursive_division (a - b, b)
        return (x+1, y)
```